# Mysql command line closes when entering the correct password (after username changed)

Tags: mysql

After I changed my MySql username from "root@localhost" to "my_name@localhost" I tried to login to my command line using the password I changed too and the command line closed.

I tried to connect to my user using MySql Shell, Visual Studio and Node.js and of them worked. When I entered to the MySql installer I tried to enter my password in "Current Root Password: " and it didnt work either.
It seems like where it askes for my username it works with the password and where its not asking my username it doesn't. I also tried my previous password on the command line and in the installer but it didnt work.

Does anybody knows why is it not working?

Comment: *Mysql command line closes when entering the correct password* Execute CLI not from the link file but from the command line. Then look for error message and fix the problem.

Comment: @Akina When Im entering the mysql keyword it replies with an error ("'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.")

Comment: Open CMD window and drag'n'drop the link to your command line client into it.

Comment: *'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file* Either start it with complete drive/path or change dir to its posession or add this path to system/session PATH variable.